# Same Name to Parent and Child Tag in JSX gives undefined

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom-events

```
class Button extends Component
{
    changeHandler = (event)=>{
        console.log(event.target.name);
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button type="button" name="text" className="btn btn-primary" onClick={(event)=>this.changeHandler(event)}>
                    <i className="fas fa-plus" name="text" onClick={(event)=>this.changeHandler(event)}></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have given same name to Button(Bootstrap) and icon (using font Awesome) and when I click on icon the console gives the value as undefined, but gives the value of name in case of button click.

Comment: Maybe the <i> element is not recognized as a valid element to have a name attr. Just guessing here.

Answer (score 0):

The `name` property only exists for certain DOM elements. `<button>` has a name property but `<i>` does not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name

If you want to get the name attribute for `<i>`, you'll have to use `getAttribute("name")`.

In your case it would be `event.target.getAttribute("name")`.